# How to correctly type Object.entries to my custom type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've these 3 fields in my form (sku, sku_variation, name) and I want to use them to create a new product.

I came up with this solution recasting the `parsedData` to unknown first but it looks completely bad practice.

```
  export type TProduct = {
    id: string,
    sku: number,
    skuVariation: number,
    name: string,
  }

  export type TCreateProduct = Omit<TProduct, 'id'>;

  const createProduct = async(parsedData:TCreateProduct) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3333/api/products/',{
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(parsedData)
    })
    return '';
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const parsedData = Object.fromEntries(form.entries()) as unknown as TCreateProduct;
    createProduct(parsedData);
  }
```

Without the `as unknown as TCreateProduct` casting the error thrown in the `createProduct` call as:

```
Argument of type '{ [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TCreateProduct'.
  Type '{ [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TCreateProduct': sku, skuVariation, name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is right to force you to do the hacky double cast as your cast is invalid.  *FormData* is only going to have values of type string or File, but the *TCreateProduct* type has properties with **number** values. This means that if a key matches one of those properties with a number value then the type of the property in the resulting object would be incorrect.

If you change your type to be a record of strings, then you can remove the extra cast to unknown.  Of course, you'll probably have an issue with *createProduct* since the request body be serialized with values for *sku* and *skuVariation* encoded as strings.

```
export type TCreateProduct = Record<Exclude<keyof TProduct, 'id'>, string>;

const handleSubmit = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
  const parsedData = Object.fromEntries(form.entries()) as TCreateProduct;
  createProduct(parsedData);
}
```

Alternatively you can map the values, doing the appropriate transformations for number values.  It won't look as neat as doing *Object.fromEntries()*, but it'll be the most accurate.

```
export type TCreateProduct = Omit<TProduct, 'id'>;
const handleSubmit = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
  const parsedData: TCreateProduct = {
    name: form.get('name') as string,
    sku: parseInt(form.get('sku') as string),
    skuVariation:  parseInt(form.get('sku') as string)
  };
  createProduct(parsedData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party library to act as a [TypeGuard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) and values validator. There are some, like [Joy](https://joi.dev/) and [Zod](https://zod.dev/). I will give you an example with Zod

```js
const createProductSchema = z.object({
  sku: z.number(),
  skuVariation: z.number(),
  name: z.string().min(3),
});

const productSchema = createProductSchema.extend({
  id: z.number(),
});

export type TProduct = z.infer<typeof productSchema>;

export type TCreateProduct = z.infer<typeof createProductSchema>;

const createProduct = async (parsedData: TCreateProduct) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3333/api/products/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(parsedData),
  });
  return '';
};

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
  const parsedData = createProductSchema.parse(
    Object.fromEntries(form.entries())
  );
  createProduct(parsedData);
};
```

Have in mind that `createProductSchema.parse` will throw an error if data is not correct